# Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to show the posts of my website in a grid view in one of the category page. For doing so, i implemented the following code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6 featured-block">
<?php while($block1Featured->have_posts()): $block1Featured->the_post(); ?>

<a class="featured_image" href="<?php the_permalink();?> "target="_blank">

 <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { 

   $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 

   $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large');

   $image_url = $image_url[0];

   if(!@getimagesize($image_url)){

   $image_url = "/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo2.jpg";

   } 

   $blogurl = get_bloginfo('url'); 

   $image_url = str_replace($blogurl, '', $image_url);

  ?>

   <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo   ($image_url); ?>&amp;w=390&amp;h=216&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" />

 <?php }

 else { ?> 


   <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo "http://www.nepaljapan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo2.jpg"; ?>&amp;w=390&amp;h=216&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" />


 <?php }?>
</a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
<p><?php echo excerpt(37); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

But i am facing the problem with this code.
This gives out the error as

Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in /home/npjp/public_html/wp-content/themes/nepaljapan/content-category.php on line 15

The line 15 on my code is

```
<?php while($block1Featured->have_posts()): $block1Featured->the_post(); ?>
```

What is the problem? Am i actually doing it correct??
Much confused.
Please help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: do debugging, add before your while loop:
`if (!is_object($block1Featured)) { var_dump($block1Featured); die(); }`
If it doesn't yield any results, check every iteration

Comment: $block1Featured isn't an object? What does `echo gettype($block1Featured)` return?

Comment: How are you compiling the object $block1Featured?

Comment: Just use while(have_posts()): the_post(); 

It's not OOP, it's procedural, so the code is right, $block1Featured is not an object.

Comment: Additional: have_posts() can be accessed as a method of an object, but that object needs to be instantiated, if you've got custom arguments out of the standard loop. You should have $block1Featured = new WP_Query(); somewhere, passing in your custom query.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the responses. I tried using your solutions. And here are what i got out of them. On adding the code if (!is_object($block1Featured)) { var_dump($block1Featured); die(); } before while loop gives NULL. Similarly echo gettype($block1Featured); this too gives NULL. And finally while(have_posts()): the_post(); makes the loop go infinite with the objects repeated. And also, i want to show the objects in two columns, but are shown in a single column. Is there anything more i should do?

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the responses. I tried using your solutions. And here are what i got out of them. Similarly echo gettype($block1Featured); this too gives NULL. @PiWi

Comment: And finally while(have_posts()): the_post(); makes the loop go infinite with the objects repeated. And also, i want to show the objects in two columns, but are shown in a single column. Is there anything more i should do? @i-CONICA

Comment: @bh.amir, then you got your answer right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom query has some problems. You can use [this guid](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) to write custom queries in wordpress:

```
<?php
$block1Featured= new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff+news' );

if ( $block1Featured->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $block1Featured->have_posts() ) : $block1Featured->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
    <!-- pagination here -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```